# Request know their location after his deny it

Tags: ios, gps, xamarin

I'm requesting know the user location (in an iOS App), but if he Deny it, I'm redirecting to other page,  but this preference is stored in some place and the app is not requesting any more his location.
Exist a way to show again the popup requesting know the location again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xamarin Recursive Location Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723129/xamarin-recursive-location-request)

Comment: You already asked this today.  Please do not ask the same question multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you only get one chance to ask for the users location.

Once that is done the user has to toggle it in the phone settings under "Location Services".